# How can I LD_PRELOAD my own compiled library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld-preload

I was wondering how this works, creating a library and preloading it so a program can use it instead of the one in the include statement.

here is what I am doing and is not working so far .

```
//shared.cpp
int rand(){
    return 33;
}

//prograndom.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 10;
    while(i--) printf("%d\n", rand()%100);
    return 0;
}
```

Then in the terminal:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC shared.cpp -o libshared.so
$ gcc prograndom.cpp -o prograndom
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/home/bob/desarrollo/libshared.so
```

and finally

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/home/bob/desarrollo/libshared.so ./prograndom
```

which doesnt print 33, just random numbers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your programs are C programs, but the `cpp` file extension implies C++, and GCC will interpret it that way.

That's an issue because it means that your function `rand` (in `shared.cpp`) will be compiled as a C++ function, with its name mangled to include its type-signature. However, in main you `#include <stdlib.h>`, which has the effect of declaring:

```
extern "C" int rand();
```

and that is the `rand` that the linker will look for. So your PRELOAD will have no effect.

If you change the name of the file from `shared.cpp` to `shared.c`, then it will work as expected.

Other alternatives, of dubious value, are:

- Declare `rand` to be `extern "C"` in your `shared.cpp` file. You can then compile it as C++.
- Force compilation as C by using the GCC option `-x c`.

Comment: If I would want to do this in c++ what changes should I have to make ?

Comment: @HoNgOuRu: You'd have to declare the `rand` you want to use as `extern "C"`, to match the `rand` you are trying to override. But you might then experience problems if you try the PRELOAD thing with a `main` compiled as C.

Comment: where should I put the extern line ? the whole purpose of this was to not touch the main program code.

Comment: I think I answered that already, when I edited. But it's better to compile `rand` as a C function. You're replacing a C function, after all.